# C# - Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'XXX'?

Tags: c#, odata

I working a project .NET core 6.0 Console with [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client).
Just try the sample code - [ODATA Batch Request](https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/wiki/Batch-requests) and got error:

> Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ODataBatch' and
> 'lambda expression'

Very sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but when I attempt to create a batch using the untyped syntax shown on the Wiki, I get an error that states Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ODataBatch' and 'lambda expression'. The code I'm using is the example code from the Wiki, shown below:

```
var batch = new ODataBatch(serviceUri);
batch += c => c.InsertEntryAsync(
        "Products",
        new Entry()
        {
            { "ProductName", "Test1" },
            { "UnitPrice", 21m }
        },
        false);

await batch.ExecuteAsync();
```

I know I'm probably missing something simple and obvious here, but any help would be appreciated. I've tried a few things to make this work, but have failed to resolve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: What c# sdk and runtime versions are you using, what C# language version and framework and what project type and version? Could it be you're missing a `using` statement to some extension class?

Comment: @JHBonarius sorry, this is .NET core 6.0 Console , had update the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `Entry` class look like?

`InsertEntryAsync` expects to receive a `string`, a `IDictionary<string, object>` and a `bool`. So for your code to work, `Entry` needs to be an `IDictionary<string, object>`.

What I think happens is `c.InsertEntryAsync` cannot be fully resolved because `Entry` is not a dictionary, and the lambda you write gets resolved as a `lambda Expression` instead of a `Func<IODataClient, Task>`. It needs to get resolved into the latter in order to use the `+` operator. See [source](https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client/blob/d9fec910cb720ea0767911021e9275eacaae7ea4/src/Simple.OData.Client.Core/ODataBatch.cs)

This code at least compiled for me:

```
var serviceUri = new Uri("asd");
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict["ProductName"] = "Test1";
dict["UnitPrice"] = 21m;
var batch = new ODataBatch(serviceUri);
batch += c => c.InsertEntryAsync(
        "Products",
        dict,
        false);

await batch.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, it works. My bad, I thought the Entry class is about the package's class and I just focus on the operator "+=".